# Displaying an OpenGL area within GTK#

Tags: opengl, mono, gtk#

I am developing a Mono/GTK# application. I need to have a "visualizer" that will display an opengl drawn area within the GTK# form. The two projects I have found myself don't seem to be maintained anymore,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkglext/

and

http://sourceforge.net/projects/glwidget/

Do you know of any other projects that allow an OpenGL area within GTKSharp?
Alternatively, is there a better way to have an application use both opengl and GTKSharp?

Comment: Does it need to be OpenGL? I managed the same thing by drawing with Cairo

Comment: @IanNorton won't the OpenGL be undoubtedly faster?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to use the GTK# integration, but [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) is by far the best OpenGL C# bindings I have ever used in C#. I highly recommend you look into it, and give the [GTK# widget](http://www.opentk.com/project/glwidget) a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robert.  I've been using OpenTK for a while and haven't had any major snags with it.  Because of this, I would recommend glwidget.